# Weird title bar on Taskbar KDE Plasma

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

I recently switched from Feren OS to Kubuntu.  After setting it up, I find this weird title bar over the taskbar which I can't remove.

I tried removing it using the edit mode.

I even removed the panel and added a default Kubuntu panel, but the issue still remains.

I think I have somehow forced title bar on the task bar.

How can I remove this titlebar?

[image: Screenshot of desktop]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have accidentally created a window rule to force "No titlebar and frame" to false for windows of type dock. If that is the case, remove it in System Settings > Window Management > Window Rules.